# Lower back arch with pushup

Tags: push-ups, form

I'm curious if the form described in this video is proper: https://youtu.be/562RZrE5r-k?t=28

When you move to 0:28, the back arch is more than evident. I believe this is highly improper form. I have the same problem, and I'm wondering what would be some exercises to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why all the downvotes but I do think the form could be improved a touch. While I would not say it is *highly improper* I think the athlete could benefit from [squeezing the glutes in a bit more](https://youtu.be/IODxDxX7oi4?t=46) to prevent that lower back rounding.

To fix this you just want to make sure you maintain tightness in your core throughout the pushup. Mentioned in that video, you'll find that the reps get harder when you start doing this so don't be surprised if you need to dial back a bit.

Comment: He's also drooping his head a lot instead of keeping neck straight

Comment: I've tried to tighten my core while doing the pushup, but my lower back still droops :( What are potential exercises can I do to fix this?

Comment: @nz_21 -- Did you try how they show in the video? Widen your foot placement a bit and push your pelvis through, squeeze your glutes kinda idea?

Comment: @C.Lange I did. I've taken a video of my form but it's only made a slight difference. I think my core/glutes isn't strong enough to maintain the alignment. :(